# How do I implement a list view inside a list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to create the following design for my android application in Android Studio, however, I am struggling to code the adapter for the inner/child List view.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ5Hn.jpg)

How exactly would one code the adapter for the inner ListView (in Java)

Prior to submitting this question, I have done some research online on how to create a design similar to the one I want. Most places I visited suggested putting a ListView inside a ListView wouldn't be a good idea. If this is so, how else could i go about creating the design above, without putting a ListView inside a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Nested ListViews are not really recommended. This looks just like a 2 panel list/detail interface, with the left side being the main list and the right side being the sublist. A simple LinearLayout can align two ListView's side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use listview inside listview? If you click the main listview item then it will expand and show some more child items or how?  My understanding is correct means Check the Expandable listview

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView

Comment: I don't want an expandable ListView, i want the secondary list to be displayed at all times, and just as depicted in the design image, the secondary list has to be placed underneath the department name